# Session atributes missing from spring session when setting inside HttpSessionListener

Tags: servlets, spring-session

In  servlet based application I want to make session replication using **Spring Session Data Redis**. Everything works fine but for csrf security we are using owasp scrfgaurd, where in that flow  session token will set at HttpSessionListener.The token is missing while validating.

I tried creating standalone code reproduce the issue.I have created SampleHttpListener and setting some attributes to the session, but these values I am not able to see at servlet level.

Please tell me anything I am missing or any other approach for this senario.

I have added source code here
https://github.com/surya0420/SpringSession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        CsrfGuard csrfGuard = CsrfGuard.getInstance();
        csrfGuard.updateToken(session);
        if(session.getServletContext()!=null){
            session.getServletContext().setAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN,session.getAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN));
        }


    }
```

Since session attributes are missing which are setting at HttpSessionListener level, so I am setting it to

```
 session.getServletContext().setAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN,session.getAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN));
```

after session got created I am setting back the attributes at filter level as shown below at Filter level

```
if(((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN) == null) {
                ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().setAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN, request.getServletContext().getAttribute(OWASP_CSRFTOKEN));
        }
```